# Ubuntu 18.04 Automatic start of VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

VPN is working fine, but now at each boot and when rising from hibernation/sleep/suspend mode I always need to engage it in the network manager.
What I want is to get it to automatically connect.

Looking for a solution I found an ask-ubuntu record telling about a setting in the network-manager that could be ticked so the chosen VPN would start automatically. 
That option wasn't there and some more searching revealed that I needed to start `nm-connection-editor` from a terminal to find the option ([Wired Connection] - [General] -"Automatically connect to VPN ...").
Indeed after launching, there was an option to start a selected VPN automatically.

Ticked the box, hit [Save] and closed the tool

In order to test, rebooted the machine.

Instead of getting the network icon eventually flanked by the VPN icon, nothing appeared in the top-richt corner of the taskbar.
I had no network connection at all.

To get things going I had to launch `nm-connection-editor` again, un-tick the "Automatically connect ..." option and hit [Save].
Immediately I got the network icons back in the top-right of the screen.

Somebody any idea/hint/other why this is not working?

Thanks

Comment: You can wrap the connection procedure in a script and use a cron to trigger the script at every interval

Comment: If you use firewall turn it off

Comment: @beingadityak
I can use a script, but then the whole purpose of the setup in the GUI goes away, is useless.

PS: I use a script that run from startup applications

Comment: @JoKeR : Firewall is turned of but still the same issue.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.  I also tried to make the VPN connection available to all users, without any difference.  Did you find something?